# null value before insertion vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, button, null

On the "convert to the pipeline" button, I have called the insertion method. but the issue I am facing is when I click on the button without entering the data in the fields. Null values entered in the DB. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JDRF.png)

how I can apply a condition to check the null value before inserting into the table in vb.net?

insertion query i am using is as below:

```
    Dim myquery As String = "Insert into Pipeline (BranchCode, CustomerName, Email, Phone, Mobile, Remarks, Converted, Converteddate, Company, CreatedBy, CreationDate) Values ('" + BranchCode + "',  '" + CustomerName + "',  '" + Email + "',  '" + Phone + "',  '" + Mobileno + "',  '" + Remarks + "',  '1',  GetDate(),  '" + Company + "', '" & User.Identity.Name & "',  GetDate())"
```

Comment: Have you ever tried validations? make a quick search and apply some validations for your input fields. More over you should use parameterization to prevent injection

Comment: Try using parameters. It is injection-safe and you can loop through your parameters and check if the value is nothing before executing the query.

Comment: i can't apply group validation as there are two buttons working against same fields. I can restrict only one button against the fields.

Comment: more over I am not applying validation to all fields some of my textboxes are free textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in different ways,

1. Do validation on each controls
2. check in sql query

**1. Validation**

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text.ToString().Trim) Then 
        Databasevaluetoinsert = DBNull.Value
    Else
        Databasevaluetoinsert = TextBox1.Text           
    End If
```

**2. In Sql Query**

Use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) (Assume Database is in Ms Sql Server)

like `ISNULL(Email, 'Values to be inserted')` in query

OR you use `Parameter` collection of Command

```
cmd=new SqlCommand("insert into tableName values (@col1,@col2,@col3)",conn)
If TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length=0 Then
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@col1",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value=DBNull.Value
else
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@col1",SqlDbType.Varchar).Value=TextBox1.Text
End If
```

As per my opinion validation is best to deal with null values